# Did anyone find gold in California before 1848?

Tags: old-west, california

Is there any documentation or evidence of anyone finding gold in California *before* the discovery at Sutter's Mill in 1848?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Spanish DID come to the New World to find Gold, and other things, but while I always thought they came across it much earlier than they did it looks like that was not so.  At least in the province of California:

> When James Wilson Marshall found gold in the tailrace of Sutter’s mill
>   on January 24, 1848, he was not the first to come across this much
>   sought mineral in California. As early as 1816, there were reports of
>   gold in the Spanish province of California. Reports and rumors of gold
>   persisted, but it was not until 1842 that there was a real gold rush
>   in the future Golden State. Either late in 1841 or early in 1842,
>   Francisco Lopez, majordomo of the San Fernando Rancho, and a companion
>   were in search of some stray cattle in the mountains near the ranch.
>   Becoming tired they dismounted to rest in San Feliciano Canyon. Here
>   Lopez whipped out his knife to dig some wild onions to eat, and in the
>   earth clinging to them he found particles of what appeared to him to
>   be gold. Using his knife he continued to mine in the vicinity and
>   found additional alluvial gold deposits.

The original source is from the California [Department of Conservation](http://www.conservation.ca.gov/cgs/geologic_resources/gold/CA_GoldDiscovery_files/Pages/GoldDiscovery.aspx), learn something new every day..

Comment: A useful book is called "Pre-Marshall Gold in California".